# table with incomplete vertical line

Tags: tables, multirow

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|}
\cline{2-4}
 & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{A}& B
\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{ |l  }{C} & \multirow {3}{*}{D} & E & F\\\cline{3-4}
&&G  & H\\\cline{3-4}
&&I& J \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you like to have something similar lie this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A}        & B \\ \hline
C   & \multirow {3}{*}{D}       & E & F \\ \cline{3-4}
    &                           & G & H \\ \cline{3-4}
    &                           & I & J \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```